# Trying to write to /tmp with C fprintf(fPtr,...)

Tags: c, file-io

So I'm trying to write some information to a file in `/tmp` from a C program (an imap server). I open the file ok, and write a test line to it ...

```
char *tmpFileName;         
char logFileName[20+17+7]; 
char buff[20]; // Date/time part of filename
time_t theTime = time(NULL);

// Generate a unique filename with todays date/time & random chars
strftime(buff, 20, "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", localtime(&theTime));
sprintf(logFileName,"/tmp/sessionInfo_%s.XXXXXXX",buff);
tmpFileName = mktemp(logFileName); // Replaces X's with random chars

if ( (logFileName == NULL) || 
     ((g_sessFile = fopen(logFileName, "w")) == NULL) )
{
  fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open session file: %s\n",logFileName);
  ... cleanup
  write_error_exit(0);
}
fprintf(g_sessFile,"This is a test msg\n");
fflush(g_sessFile);
```

I see the "This is a testmsg" line in the `/tmp` file ok... Note that `FILE *g_sessFile` is a file global... declared at the top of the source file.

In other routines in the same file, I try to write to that file...

```
fprintf(stderr,"Command received"); // Goes to /var/log file... 
int retVal = fprintf(g_sessFile,"Command received");
```

**I see the string in the `/var/log` file (where stderr gets sent), but never in the `/tmp` file ... ??**

I have tried to set permissions, and write more from other routines... NOTHING gets to the file except that first write. I've verified the `FILE *` is valid (I print its integer value -- the ptr value) ... The value returned from fprintf is 16: the number of chars in "Command received".

What am I missing? This should be simple. The only think I can think of is that imapd is started/stopped from a script in /etc/init.d ... but that script just does a

`daemon /usr/lib/courier-imap/libexec/imapd.rc start`

I've set rw permissions on the file to '666' so everyone should be able to read/write.

Comment: Did you flush (or close) the file after writing to it?

Comment: Since this question is about a runtime problem, we need a small, cleanly compiles/links program that still shows the problem.   However, your question was not clear about when your checking the contents of the file.  Does the code call `fclose()` on the `g_sessFile`?  Have you tried calling: `fflush( g_sessFile );`?

Comment: yes, I'm doing a fflush(fPtr) after every fprintf(fPtr...). The fprintf returns the correct number of bytes-- indicating success (supposedly). The file appears to be open. But I simply can't write to it from any other function than `int main()` -- which is where it is orig opened.

Comment: Yes, I've done the `fflush(g_sessFile);` and I have the `fclose()` right before exiting `main()`. I will try to create a quick, stand-alone program that demonstrates the error... But it must be something about my configuration -- or something special that needs to be done to write to `/tmp` from a daemon process... ???

Comment: Is it possible your daemon is being run in a chroot and thus the file is not where you expect it?  You may want to snoop on the file access the program makes with strace -- you should be able to see it attempting to open the file in it's output.

Comment: Also, you should be verifying that fflush() and fclose() don't return errors as write errors are often not returned until the next call due to buffering.

Comment: Thx for those suggestions... I'll check them out this morning!

Comment: So the return from fflush (in other routines) is -1 ... 'Destination address required' ... I've gotta research that, but thx.

Comment: Somehow the open FILE * was being 'lost'. I was getting ok returns from fprintf. I finally solved the problem by doing and fopen/fclose before/after every write to the log file. Not sure why I had to do this other than the executable is a daemon. Maybe the change in process ownership? However, it is at least writing to the file now. Thx for the help Phillippe